# C++ Null output when a function is called

Tags: c++, header-files

Below is a snippet of code from my main program

My H file

```
class Person{
public:
     std::string name;
     int rangeStance;
     int initialStance;

Person(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance){
     name = name;
     rangeStance = rangeStance;
     initialStance = initialStance;

     setName(getName());
     setRangestance(getRangeStance());
     setinitalStance(getRangeStance());
}
Person();
    void setName(std::string name);
    void setRangestance(int range);
    void setinitalStance(int stance);

    std::string getName();
    int getRangeStance();
    int getinitalStance();
    double impact(int rangeStance, int  initalStance);

};

class Leader: public Person {

    public:
     int popularity;
     int totalcountryVotes;

     Leader(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance,int popularity, int totalcountryVotes)
     :Person(name,  rangeStance, initialStance), popularity(popularity), totalcountryVotes(totalcountryVotes){

          popularity = popularity;
          totalcountryVotes = totalcountryVotes;
          setPopularity(getPopularity());
          setTotalcountryVotes(getTotalcountryVotes());
     }

     Leader();   
     void setPopularity(int popularity);
     void setTotalcountryVotes(int totalcountryVotes);
     int getPopularity(); 
     int getTotalcountryVotes();   
};
```

The corresponding functions in the main cpp file.

```
Person::Person() {
}

      void Person::setName(string Name)
        {
           name = Name;
        } 

        string Person::getName() {
              return name;
        }


        void Person::setRangestance(int Range)
        {

      rangeStance = Range;

        }

        int Person::getRangeStance() {
              return rangeStance;
        }

          void Person::setinitalStance(int stance)
        {

            initialStance = stance;                                            

        } 

        int Person::getinitalStance() {
              return initialStance;
        }



Leader::Leader() {

}

    void Leader::setPopularity(int popularity) {

          popularity = popularity;

     }


    void Leader::setTotalcountryVotes(int totalcountryVotes) {
          totalcountryVotes = totalcountryVotes;
     } 


     int Leader::getPopularity() {

           return popularity;
     }


    int Leader::getTotalcountryVotes() {
          return totalcountryVotes;
    }
```

Within main the needed funtions are called appropriately

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

Leader labourLeader("George Lopez",100,50,50, 75);//sets record for the labour party leader

cout << "--Party Leader--" << endl;
cout << labourLeader.getName() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

However when this snippet of code is compiled, no outcome is returned where it should be printing out "George Lopez". Im fairly "noob" with c++, am i using my contructor right or should I be delcaring it within my h file? Thankyou.

Comment: In the constructor, `name = name;` should be `this->name = name;`. Same with others. Or use member initialization: `Person(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance) :
    name(name), rangeStance(rangeStance), initialStance(initialStance) { ..... }`

Comment: Depending on what compiler you use you might get a warning like: `warning: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'std::string'  …  to itself [-Wself-assign-overloaded]  name = name;` if you don't get such a warning, then you should check the settings of the compiler if it is possible to warn you about things like that. Warnings are in general something you should not ignore. An error while compiling tells you that there is a syntax error, warnings tell you that something at runtime can/will go wrong.

Comment: And by calling all these set...() methods in the constructor you assign the member variables to themselves again. What did you think this would do?

Comment: I won't try to explain the reason for the observed behaviour. But a simple technique to avoid such problems is to avoid names of arguments to constructors (or any member function) that are the same as the name of a class member.  For example, `Person` has a member named `name` and its constructor accepts an argument with the same name.   What the compiler does with `name = name` therefore can differ from what you expect. Rename one of them (either the member or the argument) to something else. That will also be more considerate of people looking at your code - including your future self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things wrong in this code

```
Person(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance){
    name = name;
    rangeStance = rangeStance;
    initialStance = initialStance;
    setName(getName());
    setRangestance(getRangeStance());
    setinitalStance(getRangeStance());
}
```

Firstly it's not necessary to call setters and to do assignments, so lets drop those, leaving

```
Person(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance){
    name = name;
    rangeStance = rangeStance;
    initialStance = initialStance;
}
```

Now think about what `name = name` does. Does that look curious to you at all? It takes the parameter `name` and assigns it to the parameter `name`! The member variable also called `name` is completely unchanged. This situation where one name hides another similar name is called *shadowing*.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance) {
    name = name;
```

What's happening there is that it's just overwriting the *parameter* with itself, rather than copying it to the member variable. That's because the name lookup rules for unqualified names at that point prefer the parameter to the member variable. That means the member variable is being left at its constructed state, an empty string.

---

There are a few ways to fix this. The first is to simply name them differently so that there's no ambiguity, such as the common method of prefixing member variables with `m_`. That way, the statement becomes the more explicit:

```
m_name = name;
```

---

Another alternative is to be *explicit* about the one you're assigning to so that it's no longer unqualified:

```
this->name = name;
```

---

A third is to use initialiser lists where the rules are slightly different in that it uses the member variable outside the parentheses and does normal unqualified lookup *within* the parentheses:

```
Person(std::string name, int rangeStance, int initialStance)
    : name(name)
    , rangeStance(rangeStance)
    , initialStance(initialStance)
    //      ^             ^
    //      |             |
    //      |             +- normal lookup, passed-in parameter.
    //      +--------------- member variable.
{
};
```

And there's no need to have all those other statements in the constructor, such as `setName(getName())`, since you've *already* set the name.